# Group Attributes into Sets from Variant Attribute Relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a collection of Attributes using model bindings and group the attributes into sets before outputting as a resource. I have my relationships set as follows:

**Variant Model** ***App\Variant***

```
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class, 'variant_attributes')
            ->withPivot('value');
}
```

**Attributes Model** ***App\Attribute***

```
public function variants()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Variant::class, 'variant_attributes');
}

public function set()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(AttributeSet::class, 'attribute_set_id');
}
```

**Attribute Sets Model** ***App\AttributeSet***

```
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Attribute::class);
}
```

**Ideal Output**

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#718 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "essentials" => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "Essentials"
      "attributes" => array:2 [▼
        "repellendus" => array:2 [▼
          "name" => "repellendus"
          "value" => "1"
        ]
        "incidunt" => array:2 [▶]
      ]
    ]
    "interior" => array:2 [▶]
  ]
}
```

**Essentials** and **Interior** are the Attribute Sets and their associated attributes are the children with the key of attributes. The pivot value comes from the ***variant_attributes*** table. I am also binding the Product and Variant to a controller...

Now, this is what I have done, however it doesn't feel right whatsoever calling `$variant = $attribute->variants->first();` on a belongsToMany in this instance. I also feel this is overcomplicated.

```
$attributeSets = AttributeSet::with(['attributes.variants' => fn($query) => $query->withPivot('value')->where('id', $variant->id)])
            ->whereHas('attributes.variants', fn($query) => $query->where('id', $variant->id))
            ->get();

        $attributeSets = $attributeSets->mapWithKeys(function ($attributeSet) {
            $attributes = $attributeSet['attributes']->filter(function ($attribute) {
                return $attribute->variants->count();
            })->mapWithKeys(function ($attribute) {
                $variant = $attribute->variants->first();
               return [
                   $attribute['identifier'] => [
                       'name' => $attribute['name'],
                       'value' => $variant['pivot']['value']
                   ]
               ];
            })->toArray();

            return [
                $attributeSet['identifier'] => [
                    'name' => $attributeSet['name'],
                    'attributes' => $attributes
                ]
            ];
        });
```

Thanks in advance!